# Can Cypress intercept requests being made directly to a server?

Tags: testing, integration-testing, cypress

I have been trying to intercept a server request using Cypress' intercept method.
I have noticed that Cypress can intercept requests made through the front-end/browser, however, the intercept method doesn't work if I make a request directly to the back-end server.

Let me clarify what I mean:

- One thing is intercepting a request that the front-end/browser makes to the back-end server.
- Another thing is intercepting a call that doesn't use the browser but calls directly the back-end endpoint.

For example:
I can create a user using the front-end interface
or I can create a user calling the back-end endpoint directly (directly calling the server).

Coming back to my question. Is there a way to intercept a call that was made directly to the back-end endpoint?

This is what I have tried so far:

- I wrote a regex to intercept `api/v0/customers`
- I then made a request to `http://locahost:5440/api/v0/customers` (which is the URL of the server)
- Finally, I waited for the request to happen

[Timeout request using Cypress intercept method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV4aZ.png)

```
    cy.intercept(/^\/api\/v0\/customers\/$/).as('createCustomer');
    cy.request(createCustomer(customerData, headers));
    cy.wait('@createCustomer').then(({ status, body }) => {
      const customerId = body.customer_id;
      console.log(body);
      expect(status).equal(201);
    });
```

Here's the problem: There was a timeout error.

- As you can see in the image, I'm making a request to `http://locahost:5440` which is the server URL. NOTE: I made sure the server was up and running.
- The regex is also correct and it will match the endpoint `http://locahost:5440/api/v0/customers`

I suspect that intercept only works for requests being made through the browser. Is this assertion correct? I couldn't find this answer anywhere in the Cypress docs.
Is there a way for me to intercept a call being made directly to a server (not using the browser)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to intercept the requests you explicitly make with cypress, just use `.then` to get the response, like this:

```
cy.request(createCustomer(customerData, headers)).then((response) => { 
    const customerId = response.body.customer_id; 
    console.log(response.body);
    expect(response.status).equal(201);
});
```

Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Yields

Comment: I added a bit more detail to my original question. Hopefully, that clarifies things.

Comment: Edited my answer. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Your solution does work, which is good!
But I guess that there's no way to intercept a request being made directly to the backend endpoint without the use of the browser/front-end.

Comment: If by browser/frontend you mean cypress Test Runner, no, there's no way without it.